# Obter elementos de uma coluna dependente de outra

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho que fazer uma  Tabela onde indique o "name2", "local" e "name" dos animais em maior número em cada "name".

```
SELECT DISTINCT OP.nome , OP.localizacao , AD.nome_cientifico   
FROM  C AD , A OP, B CP
WHERE OP.id_aquario = CP.id_aquario AND 
      CP.id_especie = AD.id_especie AND
      NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                 FROM  C AD2
                 WHERE AD2.id_aquario = CP.id_aquario) 
GROUP BY OP.nome;
```

Tabelas

```
-- A (name,Num2, local)
    insert into A values ('Favela',1,'WE');
    insert into A values ('Lamosa',2,'NA');
    insert into A values ('Luz',3,'S0');

-- B (Num1,name,Num2, Num3) 
insert into B values (1,'Maria',1,1);
insert into B values (2,'Jorge',2,1);
insert into B values (3,'Teresa',2,1);
insert into B values (4,'Rui',3,1);
insert into B values (1,'Fran',3,3);
insert into B values (2,'Juliett',3,3);

-- C (num5,num3,name2,num4)
insert into C values (2,1,'Cao',9);
insert into C values (1,2,'Gato',8);
insert into C values (1,3,'Golfinho',7);
insert into C values (3,4,'Peixe',11);
```

Comment: Você tem que pelo menos colocar os nomes das colunas das tabelas, senão fica bem dificil imaginar qual a estrutura

Comment: Tem razão , erro meu , faltou essa parte

Comment: Pesquise o uso do LIMIT do MySql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma `subquery` para obter a quantidade de cada espécie por aquário. Porém para mostrar apenas um registro por aquário você terá que utilizar o `NOT EXISTS` comparando a quantidade usando `HAVING`. O resultado é o seguinte:

```
SELECT base.nome as aquario,
       base.localizacao,
       base.nome_cientifico
  FROM (SELECT a.id_aquario,
               a.nome,
               a.localizacao,
               e.id_especie,
               e.nome_cientifico,
               count(1) as quantidade
          FROM aquario a
               INNER JOIN especime ep ON ep.id_aquario = a.id_aquario
               INNER JOIN especie e ON e.id_especie = ep.id_especie
         GROUP BY a.id_aquario, e.id_especie) base
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                     FROM especime ep
                          INNER JOIN especie e ON e.id_especie = ep.id_especie
                    WHERE ep.id_aquario = base.id_aquario
                      AND e.id_especie <> base.id_especie
                    GROUP BY e.id_especie
                   HAVING count(1) > base.quantidade)
```

> [**Subqueries com EXISTS or NOT EXISTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
>
> Se a `subquery` retornar alguma linha, `EXISTS` é `TRUE`, e `NOT EXISTS` é `FALSE`

---

> [**Cláusula HAVING**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)
>
> A cláusula `HAVING` foi adicionada à SQL porque o `WHERE` não pode ser usada com funções agregadas (`GROUP BY`)

Um modo de simplificar a sua `query` seria criar uma `view` com os dados cruciais para a operação da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE VIEW view_quantidade_aquario AS
SELECT a.id_aquario,
       a.nome,
       a.localizacao,
       e.id_especie,
       e.nome_cientifico,
       count(1) as quantidade
  FROM aquario a
       INNER JOIN especime ep ON ep.id_aquario = a.id_aquario
       INNER JOIN especie e ON e.id_especie = ep.id_especie
 GROUP BY a.id_aquario, e.id_especie
```

E utilizá-la com a seguinte `query`:

```
SELECT vw.nome as aquario,
       vw.localizacao,
       vw.nome_cientifico
  FROM view_quantidade_aquario vw
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                     FROM view_quantidade_aquario vw2
                    WHERE vw2.id_aquario = vw.id_aquario
                      AND vw2.id_especie <> vw.id_especie
                      AND vw2.quantidade > vw.quantidade)
```

Nos dois casos o resultado será:

```
 ______________________________________________________
| aquario             | localizacao | nome_cientifico  |
| _____________________________________________________|
| Vasco da Gama       | NO          | Lutra sumatrana  |
| Bartolomeu Dias     | N           | Lutra sumatrana  |
| Infante D. Henrique | S           | Torpedo torpedo  |
|______________________________________________________|
```