# Passar uma subquery da clausula FROM para a clausula WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho a seguinte  `query` com uma `subquery` na clausula `FROM` e pretendo obter o mesmo resultado mas usando essa `subquery` na clausula `WHERE`.

```
SELECT base.nome as Aquario, base.localizacao, base.nome_cientifico
  FROM (SELECT A.id_aquario, A.nome,A.localizacao, E.id_especie,E.nome_cientifico,count(1) as quantidade
          FROM Aquario A INNER JOIN Especime Espe ON Espe.id_aquario = A.id_aquario 
                         INNER JOIN Especie E ON E.id_especie = Espe.id_especie
         GROUP BY A.id_aquario, E.id_especie) base
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                   FROM Especime Espe2, Especie E2
                   WHERE Espe2.id_aquario = base.id_aquario AND E2.id_especie <> base.id_especie AND E2.id_especie = Espe2.id_especie
                   GROUP BY E2.id_especie
                   HAVING count(1) > base.quantidade);
```

O objetivo desta query é o de indicar os nomes científicos, localização e nome do aquário, das espécies em maior número nesse aquário.

Tabelas necessárias:

```
 -- A (name,Num2, local)
    insert into A values ('Favela',1,'WE');
    insert into A values ('Lamosa',2,'NA');
    insert into A values ('Luz',3,'S0');


    -- C (num5,num3,name2,num4)
insert into C values (2,1,'Cao',9);
insert into C values (1,2,'Gato',8);
insert into C values (1,3,'Golfinho',7);
insert into C values (3,4,'Peixe',11);

-- D (Num5, Num2, perce)
insert into D values(1,1,100);
insert into D  values(2,1,100);
insert into D values(1,3,10);
insert into D values(3,3,20);
insert into D values(2,2,60);
insert into D values(3,1,50);
insert into D values(2,3,70);
insert into D values(3,2,40);
insert into D values(2,1,0);
```

Comment: Cara, vc tem que falar qual o objetivo da `query` né. Se você guarda pra você a informação você acha que alguém vai ficar se esforçando pra te ajudar?

Comment: Eu tinha metido , mas não está a aparecer :/ E já tentei editar mas também não aparece

Comment: Já está corrigido

Comment: O enunciado _"O objetivo desta query é o de indicar os nomes científicos, localização e nome do aquário, das espécies em maior número nesse aquário."_ é igual o dessa http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169108/70 que ja era duplicata?

Comment: O que eu pretendo é mudar o código acima para a clausula WHERE , não penso que seja igual , a resposta que la está não é o que pretendo

Comment: Seria bom explicar a diferença então, pois se a resposta cabe naquela, é duplicata de qq forma. O fato da resposta não atender não necessariamente justifique outra postagem. Seria bem claro deixar os requisitos diferentes em destaque (requisitos de fato), assim evita qq mal entendido ou fechamento.

Comment: Sim , está escrito na pergunta e o titulo , os requisitos é que não tenha subquery's na clausula FROM mas sim na clausula WHERE , é diferente da outra questão

Comment: E outra, no `INNER JOIN` pode `subquery`? Não tá muito claro

Comment: bom, me parece que o problema está na formulação da primeira pergunta já. De qq forma, fica a sugestão de em próximas questões detalhar melhor e de maneira mais claras para evitar uma série de postagens similares, o que inclusive pode ajudar você a obter soluções mais completas desde o início, e ao mesmo tempo aproveitar melhor o tempo de quem responder.

Comment: @Sorack O unico requisito para alterar o código acima é só mesmo que a clausula FROM não tenha nenhuma subquery.

Comment: @Bacco Ok já tou a perceber melhor como formular as perguntas

Comment: Não é melhor você fazer uma view nesse caso?

Comment: @Sorack view apesar de ser melhor para este caso , o ideal era so mesmo usar as " ideias " que estão no código acima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar de não ser a melhor forma, seguindo o que foi requerido na pergunta o resultado seria mais ou menos esse. Não é recomendável utilizar a mesma `query` tantas vezes dessa forma e está longe de ser uma boa prática:

```
SELECT a.nome AS aquario,
       a.localizacao,
       e.nome_cientifico
  FROM aquario a
       INNER JOIN especime em ON em.id_aquario = a.id_aquario
       INNER JOIN especie e ON e.id_especie = em.id_especie
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) as quantidade
          FROM especime em2
         WHERE em2.id_aquario = a.id_aquario
           AND em2.id_especie = e.id_especie
         GROUP BY em2.id_aquario, em2.id_especie) >
IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(1) as quantidade
          FROM especime em2
         WHERE em2.id_aquario = a.id_aquario
           AND em2.id_especie <> e.id_especie
         GROUP BY em2.id_aquario, em2.id_especie), 0)
GROUP BY a.nome,
         a.localizacao,
         e.nome_cientifico
```

Comment: Eu acho que me está a escapar algo que não estou a perceber , as subquery's nesse caso não estão dentro da clausula FROM ?

Comment: Eu respondi apenas que o requisito é de não  haver subquery na clausula FROM , é só mesmo isso que interessa na alteração do código que dou , é só mesmo esse o unico entrave para o código que tenho ser o correto, não percebi na altura q vc estava a falar do JOIN

Comment: Sim eu só lhe respondi isso do requisito . Esta pergunta é a mais dificil e ultima de um lote de 25 questões que tenho de fazer e nem eu próprio estou a perceber mais ou menos como tenho de fazer isto tendo em conta que não pode ser na clausula FROM , em principio as subquery's deverão estar na clausula WHERE

Comment: Esta pergunta foi uma das poucas que nao consegui alterar, porque nas outras houve muitas que também tinha feito com subquery's no FROM e tive de alterar e felizmente consegui fazer bem a maioria delas , esta ja tinha tentado mas nao cheguei a nenhuma resposta em concreto.

Comment: @ForçaChape apesar de você ter mudado de idéia quanto ao que havia colocado no comentário da pergunta, está aí a resposta.